# Let $A$ be the matrix of eigenvectors of an Hermitian $H$. Prove that $HA=AB$ with $B$ diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose we have a hermitian matrix $H$, and a matrix $A$ composed of eigenvectors of $H$, such 
that

$\langle  A_i \mid A_i \rangle =1$, where $A_i$ is the $i$-th column of matrix H.

How to prove that $HA=AB$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are eigenvalues of $H$?

Thanks

Comment: What is "such that =1, where i is the i-th column of matrix H" supposed to mean? It seems like you're missing some words.

Comment: sorry such that <Ai∣Ai>=1. That was typing error

Comment: Can you edit your post?

Comment: :) that is done

Comment: So I'm guessing you're asking why an Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized with respect to an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Sorry that is not my question

Comment: Then you should probably try to be clearer.

Comment: I mean that was not my question)))) Thank you for your link, that was very useful

Comment: @Silencer This is not a duplicate, and it is fairly clear. This is not about diagonalizing $H$. You could very well have the same eignevector repeated $n$ times in the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X_j)$ be $n$ eigenvectors for $H$, possibly linearly dependent or even repeated. So we just have $HX_j=\lambda_j X_j$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$ and no further assumption.

Then consider the matrix $A$ whose $j$th column is $X_j$. When you compute the matrix product $HA$, the $j$th column is $HX_j=\lambda_j X_j$.

Now denote $D$ the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$. When you compute the matrix product $AD$, the $j$th column is $\lambda_jX_j$.

So $HA=AD$ as they have the same columns.

**Note:** you don't need the assumption that the $X_j$'s have norm one, and more importantly, you don't need $H$ to be hermitian. $H$ could be any matrix, as long as you take eigenvectors of $H$ to form the columns of $A$.